# Poor MySQL syntax: Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'INSERT' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Trying to create a SQL query that will insert into one table a random value from a column from another table.

Just to briefly get into my database structure - I have a table for users ("aUsers") where there is a unique userID primary key. I also have a table for objects ("aObjects) that a user can have in their inventory, with objectID as the primary key. Finally there is a table which I call aInventory which does have a relatively useless inventoryID primary key but then values for userID and objectID. I can run a query to get a table of a user's inventory by running:

```
select aObjects.objectID from aUsers
join aInventory on aUsers.userID = aInventory.userID 
join aObjects on aInventory.objectID = aObjects.objectID
where aUsers.userID=108
```

I am trying to run a query that will insert a random object into a user's inventory that is not currently in the inventory. This code is successful in producing a random objectID that is not in the user's inventory:

```
select substring_index(group_concat(objectID order by rnd), ",", 1) 
FROM (select objectID, rand() as rnd from aObjects 
where aObjects.objectID not in 
(select aObjects.objectID from aUsers 
join aInventory on aUsers.userID = aInventory.userID 
join aObjects on aInventory.objectID = aObjects.objectID 
where aUsers.userID=108)) as newObject
```

However when I run it as a full insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO aInventory set userID = 108, objectID = 
(select substring_index(group_concat(objectID order by rnd), ",", 1) 
FROM (select objectID, rand() as rnd from aObjects
where aObjects.objectID not in (select aObjects.objectID from aUsers
join aInventory on aUsers.userID = aInventory.userID 
join aObjects on aInventory.objectID = aObjects.objectID
where aUsers.userID=108)) as newObject);
```

I get the "Table 'aInventory' is specified twice, both as a target for 'INSERT' and as a separate source for data" error. Obviously it does not like my specifying aInventory in the select statement while trying to insert into that table. I have seen some similar questions on here that seemed to point to just being able to rearrange the select query to make it work. However, I do not see how to do that with my code. Seeing if anyone has any suggestions or solutions. Sorry for poor formatting on these code blocks. Thanks!

EDIT: Do want to point out that I want to run this query at least three times successively. Have been able to make it work once but usually with a solution that will cause repeats of random values when done multiple times.

Comment: Not that it will directly help, but it would simplify your query (possibly making it easier to troubleshoot) if you remove `join aObjects on aInventory.objectID = aObjects.objectID1`; you don't really need it since you can just use the `objectID` field from the `aInventory` table it is being joined to.

Comment: Nice will do thanks

Comment: Actually on testing that line is necessary in order to select the objectID

Comment: In the "you don't really need it" part of my comment, I was trying to point out you should be able to `select aInventory.objectID` in that subquery. _The only way it will matter in a meaningful way is if you allow aInventory.objectID to have values not found in aObjects.objectID._

Comment: See your point now Uueerdo and @AaronDietz that actually worked when changing it to as a and then using a.userID/a.objectID. Thanks a lot. If you want to post that as an answer I will mark it as the answer. Thanks again

Comment: Try the `INSERT .. VALUES ..` syntax instead of `INSERT .. SET ..`. That would also allow you to insert three rows at once.

Comment: Last commenter actually solved it just by using aliasing for aInventory. Not sure where he went though.